# SQL Server 2008 - DECLARE function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

What does the "s" do at the end of line 8 of this query:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f8816/20/0

I can't find it anywhere and the statement won't work without it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `s` is a table alias.  It gives a name to a table or subquery used in the `from` clause.

SQL Server requires that all subqueries use aliases.  Not all databases do.

I strongly encourage you to use them.  They often make queries much more readable.

Answer (score 2):

The `s` is an alias for the result set which allows it to be referenced within the query.

> The readability of a `SELECT` statement can be improved by giving a table an alias, also known as a correlation name or range variable. A table alias can be assigned either with or without the `AS` keyword:
>
> ```
> table_name AS table alias
> table_name table_alias
> ```

[Using table aliases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455(v=sql.90).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The data set getting created in the from is given the name 's' (similar to putting "AS s") so you can reference it otherwise in the code.  Any data sets being created in a from requires a name be given to it, hence why it only works with the 's'.