# access to value generated in query within the same query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is an example of my query.  I would like to use the value created by NEWID() in the SELECT statement.

```
INSERT INTO myTable (a, b,c,d)
  SELECT NEWID() ,@b ,@c,CONCAT('-g ', (need NEWID() value here), ' -m ',@m,' -n ',@db) 
  AS parameter FROM VBsplit(@g,',')
```

Comment: This quetion should help you narrow down your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row

Comment: Maybe it could help you: http://www.michaelmerrell.com/2011/06/how-to-insert-the-same-newid-unique-identifier-into-multiple-columns/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this with a subquery:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (a, b, c, d)
  SELECT a, @b, @c, CONCAT('-g ', a, ' -m ', @m,' -n ', @db) as parameter
  FROM (select newid() as a, v.*
        from VBsplit(@g,',') v
       ) t
```

Comment: @Joe . . . It is called a table alias.  Ironically, someone else just asked this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17841576/ms-sql-2008-declare-function/17841627#17841627.

Comment: I see is it necessary in this case since it seems it is never utilized?

Comment: To answer My own question...yes